# Returning client IP with BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, bind

I'm currently looking into ways to implement something like `myip.opendns.com` with BIND for myself. Basically I want to return the client's IP using DNS. For the service mentioned above this looks something like this:

```
$ [dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
1.2.3.4
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is the IP of the client that asked for this record. Additionally a TTL of 0 makes sure that this record will not be cached (at least in theory).

Views and RPZ can probably used to implement this, although I'm not sure how exactly one would tackle this.

Comment: To clarify, you're wanting to return the requesting client's own IP address?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to return.

Answer (score 1):

Views and RPZ allow you to define static responses based on characteristics of the packet source/destination (views), query itself, or upstream authoritative server (RPZ). The operative word here is static. The packet headers and queries change, but the replies are always pre-defined and static.

What you're looking for is a form of on the fly response synthesis. BIND does not provide any functionality out of the box that dynamically computes a unique response. There is an API for writing plug-ins but I'm unaware of any pre-written ones that could solve this problem.